# Run macro (Private Sub) when checkbox is checked

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I've got the following macro to select the entire row when the active cell is selected. That's working perfectly! However, I just want to make this macro working when a checkbox is "checked"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column <> 1 Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Cells.Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
    Rows(Target.Row).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium, ColorIndex:=3
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Capture the checkbox event: Private Sub Option1Checkbox_Click()

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood your question.  Do you want the macro to trigger WHEN a checkbox is checked, or IF a checkbox is checked?

Comment: IF the checkbox is checked - the macro works

Comment: In which case, 9Deuce and New2VBA have already given you the correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for your effort and time, but I have found the solution:

If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the name of the checkbox you have. But here is what should work if it is CheckBox1

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
'do code'
Else: End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the checkbox by it's name, then select the Value property

```
CheckBoxName.Value
```

This will return true if checked and false if unchecked. So you could call

```
If CheckBoxName.Value
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Cells.Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
        Rows(Target.Row).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium, ColorIndex:=3
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   End If
End If
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to right click on the check box and choose assign macro.

http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2014/01/16/click-a-check-box-to-run-a-macro/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how relevant this is, but I've noticed you could assign macro to the checkbox directly...?